# How can I prove that if sum list = 10, then sum list == sum (reverse list)?

Tags: haskell

I thought about making a justification like this:
"Reverse does not change the values ​​in the list, so the statement is true."

But I wanted to know if I can prove it with a more complete answer.

Here are the definitions I'm working with:

```
reverse :: [a] -> [a]
reverse [] = []
reverse (x : xs) = reverse xs ++ [x]

sum :: Num a => [a] -> a
sum [] = 0
sum (x : xs) = x + sum xs
```

**Edit:** So I asked my professor and he told me to use this sum definition

```
sum :: [Int] -> Int
sum [] = 0
sum (x : xs) = x + sum xs
```

Comment: Note that you don't even need the antecedent. You can prove `sum list == sum (reverse list)` directly, assuming (+) is associative and commutative. You can do this by induction on paper/pencil; use a theorem prover (though no longer in Haskell but in a similar language), or use an SMT solver and prove it for fixed-length lists automatically. (i.e., prove it for lists of length 5, 8, 10; or whatever length you choose.) To get a general proof, you need a proper theorem prover as it would have to be inductive.

Comment: @alias you do need the antecedent in Haskell because of laziness and infinite lists.

Comment: @Noughtmare Even for an infinite list, the property is true: `bottom == bottom`.

Comment: @alias you are right, I guess it starts depending on if you use lazy natural numbers or not.

Comment: @Noughtmare I don't think (+) for lazy naturals can be commutative for similar reasons; so I guess the requirement that (+) is associative/commutative takes care of that concern. Having said that, it's a good point to keep in mind.

Comment: @alias we are getting way off topic now, but `(+)` for lazy naturals can be commutative if it is defined symmetrically using [`lub`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lub)

Comment: @luqui I had https://hackage.haskell.org/package/numbers-3000.2.0.2/docs/src/Data.Number.Natural.html#Natural in mind; but great idea in using lub to make it commutative. (Yes, we're way off topic; but this is the fun part!)

Answer (score 6):

You can't prove it in general, because it's only true for types whose implementation of `(+)` is commutative and associative. This property does not hold true for Double, for example:

```
Prelude> list = 1e16 : replicate 10 1 :: [Double]
Prelude> sum list
1.0e16
Prelude> sum (reverse list)
1.000000000000001e16
```

Comment: What if we assume the [customary properties](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/GHC-Num.html#t:Num) of `Num` to hold?

Comment: What if it's just for integers?

Comment: @Noughtmare Sure, as far as I know you can prove that, as luqui shows.

Answer (score 5):

You would prove by induction, assuming `(+)` is commutative and associative with `0` as an identity (which are usual assumptions for `Num`).  We will also have to use the definition of `(++)`, which is:

```
[]     ++ ys = ys
(x:xs) ++ ys = x : (xs ++ ys)
```

We will need to know this property about summing and appending to the end:

> **Lemma 1: `sum (xs ++ [x]) = sum xs + x`.**
>
> *Proof.* Base case:
>
> ```
> sum ([] ++ [x])
> = sum [x]       -- definition of (++)
> = x + sum []    -- definition of sum
> = x + 0         -- definition of sum
> = x             -- 0 identity of +
> ```
>
> Inductive case:
>
> ```
> Suppose  sum (xs ++ [x]) = sum xs + x  (inductive hypothesis)
>
> sum ((x':xs) ++ [x])
> = sum (x' : (xs ++ [x])) -- definition of (++)
> = x' + sum (xs ++ [x])   -- definition of sum
> = x' + (sum xs + x)      -- inductive hypothesis
> = (x' + sum xs) + x      -- (+) associative 
> = sum (x' : xs) + x      -- definition of sum (right to left)
> ```
>
> *Qed.*

Sometimes in finding these equational proofs, it is helpful to work "from both ends" -- trying to reduce both `sum ((x' : xs) ++ [x])` and `sum (x' : xs) + x` to the same thing in the middle.  The structure of a simple proof will often follow the pattern:

- use definitions (left to right)
- use the important property (inductive hypothesis, or commutativity, or what have you)
- use definitions (right to left)

Now we can proceed to the main theorem, which would proceed in a similar fashion (making use of the lemma).

> **Theorem: `sum (reverse xs) == sum xs`**
>
> [exercise for reader]
>
> *Qed.*

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: In your the inductive case of the main theorem the reverse function disappears.

Comment: @Noughtmare you're right. I'm just gonna delete the second theorem since I don't want to just straight up do this person's homework.